# How to encode the rdesktop password parameter in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, rdp, unix-shell, rdesktop

I can connect with this script from linux to a windows RDP session:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p secret123 -d DOMAIN1 127.0.0.1:33891
```

(The rdp port of the remote windows server is securely tunneled to port 33891 on localhost)

But this script does not transmit the password properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p #secret$123# -d DOMAIN2 127.0.0.1:33892
```

How do I have to encode the special chars in the password?

I am also wondering if it makes a difference if I choose /bin/sh as the shell for the script.

*Edit:*

I found out this works:

> \#secret\$123\#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend that you store the password in a file and pass it to `rdesktop` through a pipe. That way, the password won't show up as an argument in the command line when running `ps` or similar.

```
cat secretfile | /usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p - -d ...
```

To answer your question, however, simply quoting the argument may be enough to make it work:

```
/usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p '#secret$123#' -d ...
```

**Edit:**

To use a variable (the value will be visible in output from `ps`):

```
var='#secret$123#'
/usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p "$var" -d ...
```

or

```
var=$(<secretfile)    # read from a file (doesn't work in sh)
/usr/bin/rdesktop -N -x m -u Administrator -p "$var" -d ...
```

Comment: Would it also somehow be possible to use a bash/shell $variable instead of the secretfile?

Comment: @mit: See my edit.

Comment: How about something like 

    var='#secret$123#';
    echo $var > /tmp/secretfile;
    cat /tmp/secretfile | /usr/bin/rdesktop ... ;
    rm /tmp/secretfile ;

?

Comment: @mit: Why use the temporary file? You could pipe the echo into the `rdesktop` command without the file.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that does not make visible the password in the output of ps

Comment: @mit: Since `echo` is a shell builtin, I don't think it will be visible.

Comment: +1 to Dennis Williamson! I like the echo $var idea, no secret file, no ps output!

Answer (score 4):

Special characters need to be escaped with a '\' in the Linux command line.

You can post your password and I'll show you how it should look. ;) Kidding... of course.